# A member could not be added to a local group because the member has the wrong account type

Tags: sql-server

when i try congigure sql server 2005.

SQL Server Browser to Configure SQL Server Express 2005 for Remote Access.

In Sql server Browser Properties.

Built in Account
I select Network Service.
When Apply These Changes
Following Error Occure:

"A member could not be added to a local group because the member has the wrong account type.[0*8007056c]"

Thanks

Comment: I am getting the same error and have not found a solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Browser should run as LocalSystem as it does not require network resources. This service is used to map named instance to port numbers. Try setting it to LocalSystem and then restarting it.

What exactly are you trying to do?